# Ionic 2 List, Promise rejection error

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I am trying to create a simple List.  That allows you to add items and delete them.  When I try to run the ionic project through the terminal, the project runs, but does not give me any errors.  Nothing shows in the webpage.  When I inspect the page, it gives me 5 errors revolving around a promise rejection.  The error shows as:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:528 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ; at column 27 in [ngFor let todo of todoList; let i=index] in HomePage@14:22 ("
```

```
<ion-item-sliding [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let todo of todoList; let i=index">
  <ion-item>
    <h2>{{  todo  }}</h2>
"): HomePage@14:22 ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

I have created two pages; the home and add page.  Here is home.html:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>To Do List</ion-title>

  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="add()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>

</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="todos"> 
<ion-list>

<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let todo of todoList; let i=index">
  <ion-item>
    <h2>{{  todo  }}</h2>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item-options>
    <button danger (click)="delete(i)">
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      Delete
    </button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Here is home.ts:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AddPage} from '../add/add';


@Page({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public todoList: Array<string>;

constructor(private nav: NavController) { }

onPageDidEnter() {
 this.todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
 if(!this.todoList){
   this.todoList = [];
 }
}

delete(index: number) {
 this.todoList.splice(index, 1);
 localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.todoList));
}

add() {
  this.nav.push(AddPage);
}


}
```

add.html:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Add Item</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button (click)="save()"><ion-icon name="checkmark"></ion-icon>          </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="add">
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Todo Item</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="todoItem"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>  
</ion-content>
```

add.ts:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/add/add.html',
})
export class AddPage {

public todoList: Array<string>;
public todoItem: string;


constructor(public nav: NavController) {
this.todoList=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
if(!this.todoList) {
    this.todoList=[];
}
this.todoItem=" ";
}

save() {
if(this.todoItem != "") {
    this.todoList.push(this.todoItem);
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(this.todoList));
    this.nav.pop();
}
}


}
```

Any advice for me?  I am new to Ionic 2
Thanks

Comment: Did you put the whole code? It seems that home.html missing </ion-list> close tag

Comment: hey I had the same problem. clearing the cache of the browser worked for me. clear the cache from the browser that you used for running the ionic app.